# What is Management Command in redis?

Tags: redis, azure-redis-cache

The slowlog command on Azure redis returns the following item in response. What does this command do? It doesn't seem to be a command triggered from the client.

```
1) (integer) 260
2) (integer) 1660587982
3) (integer) 15508
4) 1) "ManagementCommand"
   2) "list"
5) "[::]:31729"
6) ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ManagementCommand are commands that are triggered by data plane components owned by Azure Cache for Redis for health monitoring purposes there are some Redis commands that return info about the cache itself. The [slowlog](https://redis.io/commands/slowlog-get/) is an example of this.